# Spring JPA : Query one column from the table without where clause

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am new to JPA and Spring Boot and trying to write a custom query which returns only one column from the table when the API is triggered. But I get an error doing so. It would be helpful if someone could guide me to a correct way of writing this custom query.

```
// Controller class
@Autowired
private UserTestInstanceDao usertestdao;

List<String> usertestinst = usertestdao.tempQuery();

// DAO class

public interface UserTestInstanceDao extends CrudRepository<UserTestInstance, Long> {

@Query("SELECT ti.test_name FROM test_instance ti")
public List<String> tempQuery();

}
```

Comment: Are you expecting a list as a result?

Comment: "I get an error". And you don't want to share what it is?!

Answer (score 2):

I think that your query should look like this (if you follow conventions):

```
@Query("SELECT ti.testName FROM UserTestInstance ti")
```

For this query, you UserTestInstance should look like this:

```
public class UserTestInstance {
    private String testName;

    <getters and setters>
}
```

This is because you're using JPQL, and you should be querying your objects and their declared variables. It's Spring's Data job to translate to your database specific db query.

[Spring Data](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods.at-query) documentation for reference.

Answer (score 1):

It's ok but you have two options :

1. You must put your name class in the from clause `@Query("SELECT ti.testName FROM UserTestInstance ti")`
2. Use a native query whith the real name of Database `@Query(value="SELECT ti.test_name FROM test_instance ti",nativeQuery=true)`

Answer (score 1):

I used **JpaRepository** for this purpose.

***Controller class***

```
@Autowired
private UserTestInstanceDao usertestdao;

//in method
List<String> usertestinst = usertestdao.tempQuery();
```

***DAO class:***

```
public interface UserTestInstanceDao extends JpaRepository<UserTestInstance, Long> {

    @Query(value="SELECT test_name FROM ti", nativeQuery = true)

    public List<String> tempQuery();

}
```

And these are in my ***application.properties:***

```
# DATASOURCE
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test_instance 
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# JPA
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```